# GWT 2.4 CellTable issue

Tags: java, gwt

Upgrading from GWT 2.3 to 2.4 caused a client-side exception in a class of mine that extends CellTable.  There has been no loss of functionality, but the exception is a constant development annoyance.

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): this.insertBefore is not a function

I’ve identified the line that causes this, though the exception doesn't get thrown until the table is rendering later. In a row change handler, MyCellTable removes the header Element when there are no rows in the CellTable. Here's some example code that causes the exception in 2.4, but not in 2.3.

```
CellTable<String> table = new CellTable<String>();

table.addColumn(new TextColumn<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getValue(String object) {
            return object;
        }
    }, "Col");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("abc");
list.add("def");
table.setRowData(list);

NodeList<Element> els = table.getElement().getElementsByTagName("THEAD");
if (els.getLength() == 0) {
    return;
}

final Element e = els.getItem(0);
e.removeFromParent();
```

Downgrading to GWT 2.3 fixes the problem. I tried calling headerElement.setAttribute("style", "display: none") instead of removing the element, but that doesn't look the same (it still keeps a few pixels there). I'm aware that creating a CellTable and then ripping out pieces of it is probably a bad practice.

Are there any known changes in GWT 2.4 that could be causing this problem? Can anyone think of a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same result (hiding the header) by using the CSS property: "display: none" on the "thead" css attribute of the celltable.

Here's how:

**1. Create a css file with the following entry in it:**

Globalstyles.css:

```
    .hiddenHeader thead {
        display: none;
    }
```

**2. Add this file to a client resource bundle:**

GlobalResources.java

```
    public interface GlobalResources extends ClientBundle {
        public static final GlobalResources RESOURCE =  GWT.create(GlobalResources.class);

        @Source("GlobalStyles.css")
        GlobalStylesheet styles();

    }
```

**3. In your code, you can programatically set the style when there are no rows:**

```
    cellTable.addStyleName(GlobalResources.RESOURCE.styles().hiddenHeader());
```

And to remove the style call this:

```
    cellTable.removeStyleName(GlobalResources.RESOURCE.styles().hiddenHeader());
```

Done!